# In MVC3 how to move all scripts to the bottom of the page before </body>?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, templates, view, scaffolding

In MVC3 I can easily move the jQuery script tag to the bottom of the page "_Layout.vbhtml"

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However in the ASP.NET MVC3 when you create a Controller with an editor template, the scaffolding mechanism does a good amount of work adding files to the Views folder like Create.cshtml, Delete.cshtml, Details.cshtml, Edit.cshtml, and Index.cshtml etc... and they are strongly typed.

Inside those View files, script tags are inside the `<body>`, but how can I add those tags to the bottom of the page immediately before `</body>` tag?

Comment: MVC4 has script bundling. In MVC3 if you were always using full views and no partials you could create a section for "scripts" and then in your master layout you could render them at the bottom (or even the head). The other down side is it won't work with partial/ajaxed views.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is sections http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx

Add a section just above your `</body>` tag.

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", false)
</body>
```

Then in your view you can define content that will appear in this section.

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        ...
    </script>
}
```

Comment: This works really nicely unless you have a script section in a partial view as well, in which case only the first script section gets rendered.

Comment: To be honest, you shouldn't have scripts dotted throughout your code. Inline <script> is not great for performance. I've yet to run in to the need for more since all scripts are minified and included in the project. Even loading the minified scripts that are not needed is more performant than making additional requests to the server.

Comment: I'm using partial views that contain ajax look-ups used for searches and filtering etc. Since I'm using them on several pages, it makes sense to me to have the script there. I don't know what the best practice is, but it's an approach that works for me.

Comment: Rule #1: Use the right tool for the job. If it's working well for you, then keep on that path. You're not incorrect, just differing opinions on different projects.

Answer (score 4):

You can build an html extension function, like this

```
/// <summary>
///  This section is for adding a script to the <head> tag from a partial view (or any other place)
/// </summary>
private const string SCRIPTBLOCK_BUILDER = "_ScriptBlockBuilder_";

public static MvcHtmlString Script(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Func<object, HelperResult> template)
{
    htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[SCRIPTBLOCK_BUILDER + Guid.NewGuid()] = template;
    return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}

public static IHtmlString RenderScripts(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
    foreach (object key in htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items.Keys)
    {
        if (key.ToString().StartsWith(SCRIPTBLOCK_BUILDER))
        {
            var template = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[key] as Func<object, HelperResult>;
            if (template != null)
            {
                htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(template(null));
            }
        }
    }
    return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```

Then you can use these two functions. In your _Layout.cshtml you put `@Html.RenderScripts()` in the place you want to render all your scripts.

Then you wrap all your scripts in the view like this

```
@Html.Script(
    @<script type="text/javascript">
         // Your scripts
    </script>
)
```